# Update sphinx RT index

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

I'm using RT indexes with sphinx, but actually I'm having troubles updating their structure. For example adding a new column, or a new attribute like `charset_table` to a RT index that already exists.

What I suppose I need is to reconstruct the index. But the command `indexer` is useless with this type of index.

I've considered using `ALTER TABLE` in mysql, but what about the attributes like the one I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a ALTER TABLE in sphinx QL (in latest versions anyway)

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-attach (the url is wrong!)

And there is a 'RECONFIGURE' option (see the above page)

... which can be used to an extent to change things like charset_table

But if you want to apply to the whole index, the only way is to delete/truncate the index. Which will pickup the config fresh from the config file, and then you **have to explicitly reinsert all the data again**.

Answer (score 0):

Readed the spinx document,you'll see you can't modify the structrue with field directly,you must reconstucture the conf and restart the spinx procedure.Good luck